# dataType: 'json' и JSON.parse() - есть ли разница?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Начал изучать AJAX совсем недавно. Для работы с ответом сервера как с JSON я обычно указывал в параметрах AJAX-запроса соответствующий тип ответа: `dataType: 'json'`.

Однако просмотрев здесь некоторые ответы на вопросы, увидел, что многие используют тип ответа по умолчанию, а если требуется работать с ответом в JSON-формате, используют функции `JSON.parse()`, `jQuery.parseJSON()` и т. п.

Есть ли какая-то существенная разница при использовании каждого из этих способов?

Comment: Ну, например, если придет некорректный `JSON`, то в первом случае `ajax` вызовет `error`, а во втором случае `success`

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/731c501155ef139f53029c0e58409b80f0af3a0c/src/ajax.js#L353

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что быстрее - dataType: 'json' или JSON.parse()?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735344/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b5-datatype-json-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-json-parse)