# Что быстрее - dataType: 'json' или JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть определённый ajax-запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/engine/api?action=getJson',
    cache: 'false',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        data: data
    }
}).done((data) => console.log(data));
```

Так вот, изначально этот запрос выдаёт мне просто строку, которую мне нужно превратить в JavaScript-объект. Есть два способа это сделать:

- `JSON.parse(data)`
- `dataType: 'json'`

Какой из них самый быстрый? Или есть ещё какие-то более быстрые способы парсить строку в JS-объект?

Comment: Уже был такой вопрос. Покопавшись в исходниках jquery, вы найдете там тот же самый JSON.parse, только внутри

Comment: @Darth на JSPerf есть [пример](https://jsperf.com/json-parse-vs-eval/6) с `eval`. Он на 56% быстрее. Стоит его использовать?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, а вот тут eval медленнее :-) https://jsperf.com/json-parse-vs-eval/45

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin вот оно - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/731c501155ef139f53029c0e58409b80f0af3a0c/src/ajax.js#L353

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin прикол eval'a в том, что, если туда придёт не JSON, а какой-то код - будет очень плохо =)

Answer (score 6):

Одинаково

Из-за того, что `dataType: 'json'` использует JSON.parse().

Однако первый способ выдаёт сразу объект, что намного удобнее, чем получать строку и парсить её...